# collect data from an interactive datawrapper map

Tags: python, web-scraping

I want to make a database in a CSV file with the information of a bunch of maps of USA by county from datawrapper as a project for my network science class and was wondering if I could automatize the process.

I right-clicked a map and clicked in "inspect" and saw that the information I want to collect is in a window with code in what I think is HTML but I don't know where do I start, how to do it or if it's even possible.

I'm not a tech savy person but I've learned python and C. I'll leave a screenshot of the mentioned window. When I click in a county that info changes.

[image: window]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to scrap the data from the website it's called scraping, the easy way to do it is to do it with Python using the request library to request to the website and Beautiful Soup to get the data from the page, it's not a big deal just search: **scrape data from a webpage with python**